# unable to pass props to root vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I feel like I'm struggling with something that should be very easy, though for the life of me I'm missing something.

I have a root component where I'm trying to pass in a json object as a prop however when I try to access the prop its never set.

What I have is the following component and the component mounts fine:

```
const appTemplate = `
<div class="container-fluid reference-library">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="reference-library-container" class="col-md-4 col-md-border">
                <div class="panel panel-default panel-margin-override">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-border">
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-left vertical-center arrow-container"></i>
                <div class="panel panel-default panel-margin-override">
                    <div class="panel-body" id="partial">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`;

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    template: appTemplate,
    props: ["items"],
    data: {
        loading: false,
    },
    methods: {
        useVueForContent: function() {
            this.$data.vueForContent = true;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.items); //-- always undefined
    },
});
```

what I can't get working is the following in an MVC View:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization

@{
    var contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver  
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    };

    var library = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = contractResolver
    });
}

<div id="app" :items="@library"></div>


<script src="~/js/app/components/reference-library/library.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/app/pages/reference-library.js"></script>
```

Now if I were add a child component and pass the same object everything would work fine, but the goal is to keep the library data in the root component and hove the child components use the root data, but again I can't seem to figure out how to get the data into the root component.

Comment: It does not seem that what you are trying to do is supported.  I've never had the need to do it this way, so I zeroed in on the misnamed prop initially.  You may want to check out this thread as reference which contains some various ideas for workarounds.  https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-props-to-root-instances-in-2-0/244

Answer (score 0):

According to the forum thread mentioned by Mattic Ustard, the following seems like a good solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- This is regular HTML not a Vue template - you can not use "v-bind:items" -->
    <!-- so you have to stringify the value -->
    <div id="app" items="@library"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

new Vue({
  el: 'entry-component',
  computed:
  {
    items()
    {
      return this.$el.attributes.items.value;
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h(App, {
      props: {
        // propagate ITEMS as a prop for App.vue
        items: this.$el.attributes.items.value
      }
    })
  }
})
```

And in `App.vue`:

```
export default 
{
  props: ['items']
}
```