# Integrate vue in a template with vars / props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently creating a vue app and wondering how to integrate it into a template and passing vars (props) into it.

So I basically run `npm run dev`, coding the app and all its components and so far everything is fine.

When I run `npm run build` I'll get some js in my build folder, created by webpack.

I guess (as seen before before here on stackoverflow) I can just load these files in my template, create an html-element mit the id "App" and everything works and the app initializes itself automatically.

But now my problem is: the app fires some Ajax requests, and depending on the environment the targets are different (dev: api.local, test: api.testsystem.com, prod: api.livesystem.com, ...).

And therefore I need to pass the url from outside into the app.
We don't build the app at deployment, as it's on a different repository than the "websites" using it. (Our plans are wether to copy the build files manually in these projects or offer an cdn-like url where the other projects load it). And with other projects I mean a symfony based website, or a typo3 plugin, ...

So, from React I remember you can initiate an app like `React.render('app.js', {props: 'api-url': 'http://api.local'});` (don't kill me, it was *somehow* like this...)

How do I do it in vue?

Like:

```js
new Vue(
  <template>
    <App :api-url="api-url" />
  </template>

  <script>
    import App from "path/to/app.js";

    export default {
      data() {
        api-url: "inject url here"
      }
    }
  </script>
);
```

or add an data attribute like `<div id="App" data-api-url="http://url">` and try to access it inside the app?

I've also seen something like an env-loader - but I'm not sure if this helps in my case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57370267/5962802

Answer (score 0):

You talk about different environment mode. You should read this [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html) about how to start vue app with different env mode.

You can define different .env files for each mode and populate process.env with this file, or you can start vue.js with NODE_ENV=development per example, and check for `process.env.NODE_ENV` where you need to pass appropriate variables.

Comment: Basically I excluded the environment modes as I don't want to rebuild the app for every environment-stage.
However, creating another element like `<div id="app-data" data-apiurl=""http://api.local"></div>` seems to work.